# Existence of subspace which is totally non-invariant under unitary transformation.

Tags: matrices, complex-analysis, vector-spaces

Given a complex Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ of dimension $d$ interpreted as vectorspace over $\mathbb{R}$ with dimension $2d$ and the space $L(\mathcal{H},\mathbb{C}^4)$ of all linear operators from $\mathcal{H}$ to $\mathbb{C}^4$ also interpreted as vectorspace over $\mathbb{R}$. Does there exists any subspace $E \subset L(\mathcal{H},\mathbb{C}^4)$ such that for any $B\in E$ and all $U \in U(\mathbb{C}^4)\setminus \{\pm I\}$  : $UB \notin E$?

In other words I'm looking for a real-subspace $E$ of dimension $\dim_\mathbb{R}(E) = 8d-16$ such that the map

$$R: E\subset L(\mathcal{H},\mathbb{C}^4) \to L(\mathcal{H})$$
$$ B \mapsto B^*B$$

is injective.

Comment: $R(e^{it}B) = R(B)$... Is this question related to phase retrieval in some way?

Comment: $e^{it}I$ is unitary, so thats the point. The vector space must be real.

Comment: What do you mean by "the vector space must be real"?

Comment: It should be a real subspace not a complex subspace. So a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Then you should IMHO revise your question.

Comment: Now I edited the question.

Comment: Your question has two parts, and I don't quite see that they are the same. In the second part, still $R(-B) = R(B)$.